# Is is possible for user refresh webpage and redirect to another url at same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now, I'm trying to implement refresh mechanism with redirect to other url feature in my project.

my callback for reload shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var connection; // connection will build up in the following code 
  $(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
  connection.close();
  console.log(connection.readyState);

  //I try to redirect from here
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
  return 'are you sure you want to leave?';
  });

</script>
```

The code below does not work. is any possible solution for my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `confirm` dialog to ask the user whether he wishes to leave or not.

If the user wishes to leave, you can refresh the page with `location.reload()` and then redirect him to his new destination by assigning `location.href` the value of the new href.

But of course, the previous action (refreshing) is unnecessary if you're going to redirect the user someplace else anyway, but that's up to you to deside:

```
var reload = confirm("are you sure you want to leave?");
if(reload)
{
    location.reload(); // Refresh the site, not needed really.
    location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; // Redirect.
}
```

**Edit**

To make it happen on reload we can use [unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onunload) (not tested):

> The unload event is raised when the window is unloading its content and resources. The resources removal is processed  after the unload event occurs.

Something like this should work:

```
$(window).unload(function()
{
    var reload = confirm("are you sure you want to leave?");
    if(reload)
    {
        location.reload(); // Refresh the site, not needed really.
        location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; // Redirect.
    }
});
```

Note that some browsers, like Chrome, forbid you to make an alert on the unload, maybe confirm fits into that category but feel free to try it.

Comment: how to do if I don't want to see confirm dialog when I visit the page first time?

Comment: @CWC There are so many options, it depends on how you want to implement it. Do you want this to happen automatically whenever you visit the site (Except for the first time) or do you wish to use some kind of a button? You're looking for an event listener I suppose, the event is up to you then. Feel free to ask a new question if you run into a wall and a further research does not help you to understand the problem :)

Comment: I want to make a page without any dialog  when I first visit and when user refresh page(reload) => the webpage will be redirected to http://www.stackoverflow.com (with some dialog infromation) ~ thanks